# Is it possible to receive accidental rejection for employment

Tags: rejection

I applied to a company I used to work for. I emailed my old boss and told him I applied via a job website. He forwarded my email/resume to the appropriate hiring person, as my old boss has been promoted since then. I interviewed, took like 5 minutes. Person asked why I left, and desired salary. He said I am the perfect fit and he would do anything to hire me. Four hours later I received a generic email from HR stating I am no longer being considered for the position. Was this maybe an accidental email? Job posting on generic site is still up, have not been rejected via generic job site.

Comment: Yes. You should reach out and ask about the incongruity.

Comment: You can reach out the "old boss" or to the current "hiring manager". It could be either way: accidental rejection or intentional rejection. Also, the position may have been canceled for tons of reasons, and they have not got time to take it down from the job site yet.

Comment: Yes, accidental rejections happen all the time, simply because many companies automate them.

Answer (score 5):

Of course it could be accidental.

Because you were told you were a perfect fit and would do anything to hire you, you should get in touch with the company to explain your experience and ask if the email is accurate.

It's of course possible they found a "more perfect" candidate, but it is tough to quantify when the interview goes for 5 minutes.

Comment: Or they told everyone the same thing, or they actually meant it, and your old boss prevented your rehire, or Tim lost his keys…

Comment: @Donald Spot on. There are a gazillion potential reasons. They may not be honest but at least you know where you stand.

Comment: @Donald, What does "**Tim lost his keys**" mean ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 - It’s a reference to a justification to downvote questions, or in the context of this question, somebody named Tim lost his keys so he decided not to give the job to the author.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 FYI - Here is the full reference to _the lost keys_: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397 Fun to read for sure.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Reach out and get an explanation from your old boss.

What may (and probably did) happen is that your resume went into an ATS system, and because you missed one or two parameters for the job, you got an automatic rejection from the system without anyone even seeing the resume. It happens quite often - most people, once HR writes out the job description, don't qualify to apply for their own jobs.